# How to make a React Native TextInput accept ONLY NUMBERS and make it accept numbers 1 to 10 ONLY?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

How to make a **React Native TextInput** accept **only numbers** and make it accept **numbers 1 to 10 only**?

For example, **say I input 11**, **the value should automatically change into the maximum allowed**, that is, **10**.

And **when I input 0**, the **value should automatically change into the minimum allowed**, that is, **1**.

As of now the only thing I have done are:

```
<TextInput
style={styles.input}
placeholder="Maximum of 10 passengers only"
maxLength={2}
keyboardType={"numeric"}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
...
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
....

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if(value === "") {
      return;
    }
    if(+value > 10) {
      setValue(10)
    } else if (value < 1) {
      setValue(1);
    }

  },[value])


<TextInput
      keyboardType='numeric' 
      maxLength={2}
      value={value.toString()} 
      onChangeText={(e) => {
      setValue(e)
    }} />
```